# How to access typescript interface property array?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

If I have three interfaces like this:

**registration-pivot.ts**

```js
export interface RegistrationPivot {
    THead: RegistrationPivotRow;
    TBody: RegistrationPivotRow[];
}
```

**registration-pivot-row.ts**

```js
export interface RegistrationPivotRow {
    CellList: RegistrationPivotCel[];
}
```

**registration-pivot-cel.ts**

```js
export interface RegistrationPivotCel {
    content: string;
}
```

Okay say now that I call a get API and put the object from the API to `registrationPivot` (also what do you call that: a property? a list? an empty object?):

```js
registrationPivot: RegistrationPivot = {} as RegistrationPivot;

searchRegistrationStatistic(){
    this.registrationApi.getAllRegistrationStatistic().subscribe(res => {
    this.registrationPivot = res;
    });
}
```

In my html how do I get the values from the `registrationPivot`?.

- I tried doing `registrationPivot.THead.CellList` but that does not work.
- Basically I have to loop through all the Cells inside the THead element (same with the TBody) but with the code I have I do not know ho to achieve it. Can someone please help me understand how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your interfaces and way of accessing data defined by such interfaces - are correct. As you can see in below example (I've run it in browser on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nug7aqm/1/)).

```js
interface RegistrationPivotCel {
  content: string;
}

interface RegistrationPivotRow {
  CellList: RegistrationPivotCel[];
}

interface RegistrationPivot {
  THead: RegistrationPivotRow;
  TBody: RegistrationPivotRow[];
}

const example = {
    THead: {
    CellList: [
      {content: "title"}
    ]
  },
  TBody: [
    {
      CellList: [
        {content: "row A"},
        {content: "row B"}
      ]
    }
  ]
}

console.log(example.THead.CellList)
/*
[
  {
    "content": "title"
  }
]
*/
```

Probably data you are returning from `this.registrationApi.getAllRegistrationStatistic()` is not implementing these interfaces. Try even to `console.log` your `res` and see if this data is really implementing these interfaces.

Comment: Yeah it does work for you, i still have to debug a little bit because if i `console.log(res)` i'll get undefined ahaha but thanks for the answer

Comment: So i think there is some problem with my Observable type when i call the api... i can see the object if i inspect the preview

Comment: It does not work for me, because it says is not an iterable. I tried doing this `<th *ngFor="let data of registrationPivot.tHead.CellList">{{data.content}}</th>` but it does not display the content of the cellulare and in the console it trhows erros, any idea?

Comment: @ludodev88 firsto of all - what problems? Content of these errors is very important in this case ;) also can you prepare some stackblitz with your problem?